# Utilisation de « euro » ou de « d'euro »

Tags: grammaire, unités

Dans le cadre d'un devoir où je doit écrire un programme qui convertit un montant d'euro écrit en chiffres vers ce montant écrit en toutes lettres, j'ai remarqué que l'on dit parfois « euros » et d'autre fois « d'euros » mais je ne comprends pas la règle sous-jacente. Cela pourrait également me faire rater des cas auxquels je n'ai pas pensé. 
Est-ce que l'un d'entre vous saurais me l'expliquer ?

Exemples liés au contexte:

- « deux mille euros » mais « deux millions d'euros »
- « quatre-vingts euro » mais « quatre-vingts centimes d'euro »

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La différence provient de ce que

- quatre, vingt, cent, mille... dans ces contextes sont des **adjectifs** (numéraux).
  on a alors mille euros avec *mille* adjectif *"numérant"* *euros* substantif.
- alors qu'au même titre que *centaine*, *million*, *milliard* sont des substantifs se référant non à un nombre mais à une **quantité**.
  On ne peut alors avoir la construction *quantité* + substance. On à nécessairement une *quantité* **de** substance. D'où le million **d** ' euros.

EDIT : Évidemment cette explication vaut aussi pour *centimes **de***, *centime* étant lui aussi un substantif, tout comme d'ailleurs la quantité équivalente de *centième*.

On peut chaîner cette construction ad libitum et, comme pour le *mille millions **de** mille sabords* cher au Capitaine Haddock, parler de 
*mille millions **de** milliards **de** centimes **d** ' euros*... ;-)